# Django: Selecting objects while excluding subclassed objects?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models in a Django app:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
...

class Pet(Animal):
...
```

I want to select all `Animal`s, but excluding `Pet`s. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Animal.objects.filter(pet=None)
```

Assuming that `Animal` is not an abstract model.